# Injecting environment variable to docker containers using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there a way to inject environment variables to **all** of my docker-compose services, without explicitly declaring them in each service's configuration?

Comment: no you have to tell the service about those in one or anther way. May it be env_file or environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1)using the env_file directive

you can use the `env_file` directive within your `docker-compose.yml` file

> You can pass multiple environment variables from an external file
> through to a service’s containers with the ‘env_file’ option, just
> like with `docker run --env-file=FILE ...`:

you will have to declare the env file for each service that will use it and that is it.

### example :

the `docker-compose.yml` file :

```
version: "3"
services:
  database:
    image: "ubuntu"
    tty: true
    env_file:
     - same-variables.env
  web:
    image: "ubuntu"
    tty: true
    env_file:
     - same-variables.env
```

the `same-variables.env` file

```
 IS_DOCKER_COMPOSE=yes
```

then if you do opening a terminal :

```
docker exec -it <docker_container> "echo $IS_DOCKER_COMPOSE"
```

result will be :

```
yes
```

## 2)using the .env file in project root

According to the doc: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file

> You can set default values for any environment variables referenced in
> the Compose file, or used to configure Compose, in an environment file
> named .env. The .env file path is as follows

Create an .env file as the root of your project as follow.

### example :

your `.env` file :

```
TAG=v1.5
```

your `docker-compose.yml` file :

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: "webapp:$TAG"
```

organization of your project should be :

```
root_folder
|-.env
|-docker-compose.yaml
```

with the .env file with all your variable
the env file will work for all of them at the same time

Comment: But that still requires me to add each env variable to every service i want it available in, no?

Comment: I added a new answer, you will have to declare the env_file each time you have a service but you can use only one env file for all services and that is it. (inside the same-variable.env add all your env variables)

Comment: Yes, thank you, but that's exactly what i wanted to avoid

I basically want to inject an env variable to all services which indicates that they run under docker compose - but i don't want to be required to add it for each service i add (the reason is that i won't be the only one adding services..)

Comment: will using `env_file` add all of the variables in the `.env` file to the container, or i'll have to explicitly add the `environment` section to each service?

Comment: yes it will work I am adding an example in the answer.

Comment: May you add an upvote to the answer to help others to find this solution please :)

Comment: I can't currently (coz of my reputation) :/

Comment: I gotchu @blackbird. Good answer